# Looking for bootstrap-modal.js and ember-data-localstorage.js

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, bootstrap-modal

I started reading [Ember.js in Action book](http://www.manning.com/skeie/).

In the very first app, author advises to **download** a number of js files.

There are 2 which I can't figure out where to download from:

1. `bootstrap-modal.js`
2. `ember-data-localstorage.js`

Googling didn't give any results.

Although, these scripts available in the book's [source code](https://github.com/joachimhs/Ember.js-in-Action-Source/tree/master/chapter1/notes/js/scripts), they're 2 years old. I wonder if those scripts are not used anymore or I will have to make them on my own...

Comment: This is really old stuff. I'd strongly recommend reading https://leanpub.com/ember-cli-101 instead.

Comment: Thanks, that books looks interesting. I also bought https://pragprog.com/news/deliver-audacious-web-apps-with-ember-2